# Unique Replacement of Symbol

Tags: replacement, symbolic, symbols

I have

```
formular = a[0]*e[0] + a[0]*e[1] + b[1]*e[0] + c[0]*e[1]
```

and I want to replace every `e[_]` into some unique symbol:

```
formularNew = UniqueReplacement[formular]
formularNew = a[0]*uu[1092873] + a[0]*uu[76341]  + b[1]*uu[3451] + c[0]*uu[97415]
```

I have tried:

```
formularNew = formular/. {e[_] -> uu[], f[_] -> ll[RandomInteger[1000000]]}
```

but it applies the random number directly, thus it leads to

```
formularNew = 2 a[0]*uu[885866] + b[1]*uu[885866] + c[0]*uu[885866]
```

I would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: Use `:>` instead of `->` for the replacement rule.  This is analogous to `=` vs `:=`.

Comment: I would do something like `Module[{i = 1}, formularNew = formular/. {e[_] :> ll[i++]}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possibility. Gather the variables of interest e.g. using `Cases`, then do a replacement using `Unique` to create the new symbols.

```
formular = a[0]*e[0] + a[0]*e[1] + b[1]*e[0] + c[0]*e[1];
evars = Union[Cases[formular, e[_], Infinity]]
replaced = 
 formular /. Thread[evars -> Table[Unique[uu], Length[evars]]]

(* Out[92]= {e[0], e[1]}
```

If you really want the `uu[randominteger]` style of replacement variable, could do as below.

```
replacedB = 
 formular /. 
  Thread[evars -> 
    Map[uu, RandomSample[Range[10^6, 2*10^6], Length[evars]]]]

(* Out[95]= a[0] uu[1443544] + b[1] uu[1443544] + a[0] uu[1743614] + 
 c[0] uu[1743614] *)

Out[93]= uu$8369 a[0] + uu$8370 a[0] + uu$8369 b[1] + uu$8370 c[0] *)
```